# Gradle Build Error In Unity with error A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I had an error about android.enableR8 but I set it to true and the error disappeared

now I'm trying to build an APK but always getting the following two errors:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/username/workdir/appname/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/launcher/build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> No signature of method: build_x0sqiuspfvwz7kaxn7p25y4z.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_x0sqiuspfvwz7kaxn7p25y4z$_run_closure2) values: [build_x0sqiuspfvwz7kaxn7p25y4z$_run_closure2@2449292e]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:190)
```